# Are quantum computers just massively parallel computers?

Tags: quantum-computer

I am a computer engineering major so I do not understand a lot of quantum science but from what I hear about quantum computers, it sounds like they are just massively parallel computers.

In quantum computers there are Qubits which are in a superposition state of 0 and 1. Two qubits are in the states 00, 01, 10 and 11 states simultaneously.

Now let us take a look at a NP-complete problem, [boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). If it is a three variable satisfiability problem, classical computer would have to try every single combination, one after another. (000,001,010...)

But say if my computer has 8 cores I can ask each core to solve for just one of these combinations. So I will get the solution in polynomial time. For a N variable satisfiability problem I need 2^N cores and I will still be able to solve in polynomial time.

My question is, does the quantum computer do just that or is there more to it?

I am learning OpenCL and it utilizes the GPU which has a massively parallel architecture having thousands of cores(kind of). Then can it emulate a quantum computer to a certain extent?

Comment: Why don't you read about the Shor factoring algorithm and think about how you would implement it on a classical computer?  Working this out yourself will, I think, give you a much better feel for the issues than any answer anyone can give you.

Comment: Shor algorithm is in my todo list for a while. I should look it up.